# subdomain on different Host through NS record

Tags: laravel, heroku, dns, subdomain, nuxtjs

I have a **NuxtJS** app hosted on `vercel.com` and my **Laravel** app on the `heroku.com`

What i am trying to do here is

1. Main domain `prizebond.top` to point to NuxtJS app on vercel
2. And subdomain `backend.prizebond.top` to point to Laravel app on Heroku

I am using cloudflare for now for DNS management.

following is the configuration on cloudflare.

[image]

The main domain works great, but it the subdomain that is not working and says timedout.

I have got the DNS target from `Heroku` after adding the domain
[image]

I have checked multiple times the DNS target is correctly set as NS value.

My Heroku app is working fine on the Heroku domain.
`http://prizebondtop.herokuapp.com/`

Following is the DNS Target I got from Heroku

`sheltered-ferret-nam0ouzp19eicrfkkjmf75ki.herokudns.com`

So I tried to add NS record with it pointing to mentioned DNS Target `sheltered...`

it didn't worked, then I tried to point the NS record to `backend.prizebond.top` as this is added on Heroku, this also didn't work for me.

This is the **updated** configuration, still didn't work.

[image]

How to redirect my subdomain to Heroku app?

Comment: You need CNAME record to `sheltered-ferret-nam0ouzp19eicrfkkjmf75ki.herokudns.com`

Comment: Yes, i already did it with CNAME, tried CNAME and it worked.

But I don't know why other posts that i searched on google reffering me to the NS?

As i have tried the NS and it didn't seemed to work for me. Not sure if using CNAME is the right way to redirect subdomain to other server.

Comment: You would use NS record if you want to delegate authority for your subdomain to another DNS server (and then that DNS server should have all the records for your subdomain).

Comment: @SizzlingCode Hello, did you solve your issue by setting a type=CNAME, Name=<subdomain> Target=<heroku_dns_target>? I have that right now and it's not working for me....